# How to detect line break in a String using UnityScript?

Tags: unity, unityscript

Code:

```
var i:int=0;
var text:String; 
var compare:String="";
var isFound:boolean=false;
function Start(){
text=AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/words.txt",TextAsset).text;
}

function Update(){
    if(!found)
   com("textToSearch");
  }

 function com(s:String){
    if(i<text.Length){
    comText=comText+text[i];
    if(//condition for line break)
    if(comText==s){
       print("found");
       found=true;
    }
   else{
         comText="";
      }
   i++;
   }

 }
```

In the text document each word ends with a line break. So if I just found a condition for a line break then I can easily search through the document.

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks are '**\n**' or '**\r\n**' depending on the file you are reading.

So your conditions would be something like :

```
if(myLine.Contains("\n")){
    //DoSomething
}
```

Comment: FWIW, `myLine.Contains("\n")` will return true anytime `myLine.Contains("\r\n")` does, so, `myLine.Contains("\r\n")` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, the idea was to use one of those. It was ambiguous I updated.